# SQL. Как исключить данные из выборки в таком случае

Tags: sql, firebird

[image: Данные]

Хочу исключить из выборки строки у которых в колонке **E** стоит значение **2**, но при условии что в колонке **D** стоит **5**. Полностью исключать все пятерки или все двойки нельзя. Подскажите плз как это можно реализовать.Все данные выбираются из одной таблицы. База данных на Firebird-2.0.3.12981

Comment: Какая у вас БД?

Comment: Firebird-2.0.3.12981

Comment: что то в духе `where not (E=2 and D=5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант:

без подзапроса (как подсказывает коллега)

```
SELECT 
*
FROM YouTable
where not (E=2 and D=5)
```

или

```
SELECT 
*
FROM YouTable
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM YouTable WHERE e=2 AND d=5)
```

Comment: Эм, а без подзапроса точно нельзя? Как я выше в комментарии написал?

Comment: Спасибо, конечно можно)